# Cargo una pagina dentro de un div con jquery, se carga el archivo JavaScript pero las funciones no

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un html con un li, para que al apretar uno, me carge en un div, un html, (que dejo mas abajo). El html se carga, y el archivo de JavaScript tambien. El html que se carga correctamente, tiene un boton, y quiero que al apretar el boton, muestre un alert. El archivo JavaScript se carga, pero la funcion click no.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="funciones.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Cabecera -->
    <header>
        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                        <li><a id="inicio" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a id="donar" href="#">Donar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
  <!-- Cuerpo -->
    <main class="container-fluid">
        <section class="row">
            <article class=".col-12 .col-sm-12 .col-md-12 .col-lg-12 .col-xl-12 mostrarAqui">

            </article>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="container-fluid">
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el archivo de jquery para que se muestre el html en el div.(Sin problemas)

```
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio() {
    //Cuando carge el documento, estara escuchando que boton pulsamos.
    $(document).ready(function () {  

        $("#inicio").click(function(){
            $(".mostrarAqui").load("hola.html");
        })

        $("#donar").click(function(){
            $(".mostrarAqui").load("adios.html");
        })
    })
}
```

Y este es el html que tiene que cargar en el div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Hola</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviar">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el JS para que haga el alert que nunca hace.

```
   window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

    function inicio() {
        document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", enviar);
    }
    function enviar() {
        alert("Bienvenido: " );
    }
```

Mi pregunta es ¿por qué no hace el alert?, el debug no muestra nada, y otra pregunta, ¿es correcto hace una pagina entera con sus etiquetas para solo cargar el div con el input y el button o hay otra manera?

Comment: puede que estés "encimando" tus scripts de js, quizá solo con que lo tengas en la pagina principal y no dentro del html que cargas en el div. Puedes usar handle-bars de js quizá eso te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que he podido comprobar es que el window.addEventListener del JS en hola.html, no ejecuta la acción y no por tener el mismo nombre del método en otro JS, sino que el objeto window no está siendo cargado de nuevo y por tanto no ejecutará ni hará posible lo que deseas en este caso. Básicamente, estamos añadiendo más contenido al DOM, cargando eso si, el nuevo HTML y sus JSs, pero no el objeto window. Sin embargo, si pruebas a ejecutar solo hola.html por separado, te funcionará sin problemas, y ahi entenderás justamente lo que aquí te intento explicar. Por ello, una opción que te podría dar sería colocarlo de esta manera:

```
document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", enviar);

function enviar() {
    alert("Bienvenido: " );
}
```

Aquí te dejo un enlace que habla sobre el objeto Window en w3school:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Comment: Muchisimas gracias